# Dynamic condition in Query cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

In cake php how can i assign dynamic condition in query (greater than, less than ).

I am using like this :

```
 $condition['Product.price >='] => $price_low;
 $options=array('conditions'=>$condition);
 $data=$this->Model->find('first',$options);
```

It is not working properly

```
condition array contains number of dynamic conditions including 'LIKE',
```

Error is that only two digits of low and high value are considered.
For example if price low is 112 and price high is 184, result will consist of all values with first two digits within the range 11 -18

Ex :

```
15,114,111111,1834,16
```

Comment: Buddy are you asking about DB query condition in cake PHP?

Comment: Please write your complete query so that i can have an idea.. the code you write that should work.

Comment: for some values it is giving output

Comment: I want to check both greaterthan and less than